# Getting the requirements for a function within the function call

Tags: c++, function

When calling a function that has requirements that are obtained in other functions, is it better or worse to have the function call to one of the requirements within the overall function call?

I've made this simple example to demonstrate:

```
int amountToMultiplyBy(int multiplyAmount)
{   
    int temp;
    std::cout << "how much do you want to multiply by: ";
    std::cin >> temp;
    multiplyAmount = temp;
    return multiplyAmount;
}
void sumOfNumbers(int numOne, int numTwo, int multiplyAmount)
{
    std::cout << "1: " << numOne * multiplyAmount << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2: " << numTwo * multiplyAmount << std::endl;
}
```

`main` version 1:

```
int main()
{
    int multiplyAmount;    
    sumOfNumbers(5, 10, amountToMultiplyBy(multiplyAmount));
    return 0;
}
```

`main` version 2:

```
int main()
{
    int multiplyAmount;
    multiplyAmount = amountToMultiplyBy(multiplyAmount);
    sumOfNumbers(5, 10, multiplyAmount);    
    return 0;
}
```

In version 1, the call to `amountToMultiplyBy` is within the call to `sumOfNumbers`, obtaining the value for `multiplyAmount` during the call.

In version 2, `amountToMultiplyBy` is called first giving `multiplyAmount` its value, which is then included in the call to `sumOfNumbers`.

I'm just curious as to know if this is either good practice, bad practice, or simply just exactly the same?

Comment: Version 2 is clearer, if you write for the code readers...

Comment: It is good practice to avoid directly `cin` a value to a parameter. Better to make a temp variable and return the temp variable. Obviously that doesn't answer your question though.

Comment: In your case there's not much difference aside from clarity and style, however be careful passing assignment expressions as function arguments; the order in which the expressions are evaluated is not defined and may not be the same order in which they appear in the function signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling multiple functions as parameters of another function is not a good practice. Since we cannot guarantee the order of inner functions get called. If the inner functions have data dependency it may creates some bugs.

As said so, in your case, since there is no multiple functions calls from another function's parameter list either way is good to go.

Comment: So in the basic example above, it doesn't really matter due to its simplicity. But in more complex programming its a practice that should be avoided?

Comment: @MLMLTL yes, we can say so.

Comment: @MLMLTL, just remember not to go overboard with this good practice. Cluttering a scope with variable names to store the transient results of simple non-throwing functions, is a sure way to make your code too verbose.

Answer (score 1):

If you compiled that two versions and see the output assembly code:

Version 1:

```
00af 8B45FC         movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
00b2 89C7           movl    %eax, %edi
00b4 E8000000       call    _Z18amountToMultiplyByi
     00
00b9 8945FC         movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
00bc 8B45FC         movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
00bf 89C2           movl    %eax, %edx
00c1 BE0A0000       movl    $10, %esi
     00
00c6 BF050000       movl    $5, %edi
     00
00cb E8000000       call    _Z12sumOfNumbersiii
```

Version 2 :

```
00af 8B45FC         movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
00b2 89C7           movl    %eax, %edi
00b4 E8000000       call    _Z18amountToMultiplyByi
     00
00b9 8945FC         movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
00bc 8B45FC         movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
00bf 89C2           movl    %eax, %edx
00c1 BE0A0000       movl    $10, %esi
     00
00c6 BF050000       movl    $5, %edi
     00
00cb E8000000       call    _Z12sumOfNumbersiii
```

you will find that both are exactly the same output.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int multiplyAmount = amountToMultiplyBy();
    sumOfNumbers(5, 10, multiplyAmount);    
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main()
{
    sumOfNumbers(5, 10, amountToMultiplyBy());    
    return 0;
}
```

The former is better for debugging because you have the value in a variable. The latter is shorter.

Warning: The latter form could be used only if there is a single function with side effects. If there are more such functions their evaluation order is undefined.

Comment: I have edited my answer. By the way, the parameter of your function `amountToMultiplyBy` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

your `amountToMultiplyBy` function code is weird, why give it `multiplyAmount` as argument if you don't use it ?? this is better :

```
int amountToMultiplyBy()
{   
    int temp;
    std::cout << "how much do you want to multiply by: ";
    std::cin >> temp;
    return temp;
}
```

and this is a better call :

```
sumOfNumbers(5, 10, amountToMultiplyBy());
```

since you don't need a new variable to store your data

**PS**

```
int multiplyAmount = amountToMultiplyBy(multiplyAmount)
```

is better than

```
int multiplyAmount;
multiplyAmount = amountToMultiplyBy(multiplyAmount)
```

better initialize variable in declaration

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I answered her question

Comment: @MLMLTL I am sorry, I don't remember why I said that